# Alternative way to add footnote to a Google doc programatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, footnotes

I am trying to add footnotes programatically to a Google Doc using Google App Script.
It appears that such a function does not exist.

The goal is to find abbreviations from a list and insert the footnote that will describe what this abbreviation stands for. The input for the correspondance is a GSheet with one column of abbreviations and one columns of significations. The input data for the text is simply a GDoc with text on it (and title, paragraphs etc.)

I thought of making a python script simulating a user input of shortcuts and text on the GDoc web window, but I would need to also move programatically the cursor in order to put it on the right.

Do you think of any good way of achieving this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a class Footnote, see this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266630

Answer (score 2):

From the question

> I am trying to add footnotes programatically to a Google Doc using Google App Script. It appears that such a function does not exist.

Documents Service hasn't that method, but the Advanced Document Service has it:

```
function myFunction() {
  const documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const requests = [
    {
      createFootnote: {
        location: {
          index: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({requests:requests},documentId)
}
```

Resource

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs