# How to find the index of a specific string in relation to the document's body, to use with the api?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to replace text, matching a specific regex, by a footnote with this text.

1. I know how to find each occurrence of the regex (thanks to some other post here)
2. I know how to create footnotes using API (thanks to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959274/alternative-way-to-add-footnote-to-a-google-doc-programatically))
3. I guess, I even know how to put the text into the footnote section corresponding to the created footnote

But I need an index of the position in the text and my search (done by script, not by request) returns some abstract starting position in the "Element", which is not  the index from the start of the document's body( which is  what the api wants).

Where can I get the index?

```
function makeRef() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
  const documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();

  var myRegEx = '\\([a-z,A-Z]+?.+?,.+?[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)'

  var foundElement = body.findText(myRegEx);

  while (foundElement != null) {
    // Get the text object from the element
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
    // Where in the Element is the found text?
    var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
    var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    var requests = [
    {
      createFootnote: {
        location: {
          index: start 
        }
      }
    }]
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({requests:requests},documentId)
    // Find the next match
    foundElement = body.findText(myRegEx, foundElement);
  }
}
```

The problem is: how do I get the index of the place where I need the footnote?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your expected result, do you want to set only a value of `\\([a-z,A-Z]+?.+?,.+?[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)` as a footnote? Or, do you want to set the whole paragraph including a value of `\\([a-z,A-Z]+?.+?,.+?[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)` as a footnote? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I want to have a footnote in the document where the regex is located, while its value (e.g., "(France, 1968)") to become the corresponding text in the footnote.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your expected result. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your expected result.

Comment: @Cooper But that would only return the offset within that element. OP needs the offset from  document's body: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure#start_and_end_index

Comment: @Tanaike Suppose I have a text 

Harry Potter is a magical child (Rowling, 1996).

I want it to become Harry Potter is a magical child^k (k is the number of footnote)

And then in the footnote below the page the text will be 
^k Rowling, 1996

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your expected result, you want to modify a text from `Harry Potter is a magical child (Rowling, 1996)` to `Harry Potter is a magical child^1` and you want to put `^1 Rowling, 1996` as a footnote. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, I'm worried that the script will be a bit complicated. So, in this case, in order to correctly confirm your actual situation and test it, can you provide a sample Google Document?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for your time! You got it absolutely right!
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13BwKKmxYxvRnx5bWuDLxwdOgq3dtDBi_6ag3XhWQ28o/edit?usp=sharing
Here is a sample document with absurd text, where I input three citation references which need to be transformed into footnotes -- very much like my original document. 

I have already got the point that it's going to be complicated :) Ready to suffer, but I simply got stuck with the total inability to locate the positions automatically.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Google Document, I prepared a sample script for achieving your goal. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to modify a text from `Harry Potter is a magical child (Rowling, 1996)` to `Harry Potter is a magical child^1` and you want to put `^1 Rowling, 1996` as a footnote.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

I thought that it might be difficult to directly obtain the index for using Docs API from your showing script. In this case, in order to obtain the index, how about using Docs API? In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document and enable Docs API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

```js
function myFunction() {
  const myRegEx = '\\([a-z,A-Z]+?.+?,.+?[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)'; // This is from your script.

  // Retrieve the initial object from Google Document.
  const documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const obj1 = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content;

  // Retrieving texts and creating footnotes.
  const r = new RegExp(myRegEx, "g");
  const { requests1, texts } = obj1.reduce((o, e) => {
    if (e.paragraph) {
      e.paragraph.elements.forEach(f => {
        if (f.textRun) {
          const m = [...f.textRun.content.matchAll(r)];
          if (m.length > 0) {
            m.forEach(c => {
              o.texts.push(c[0]);
              o.requests1.push({ createFootnote: { location: { index: f.startIndex + c.index - 1 } } });
              o.requests1.push({ deleteContentRange: { range: { startIndex: f.startIndex + c.index, endIndex: f.startIndex + c.index + c[0].length } } });
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return o;
  }, { requests1: [], texts: [] });
  const { replies } = Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests: requests1.reverse() }, documentId);
  const footnoteIds = replies.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e && e.createFootnote && e.createFootnote.footnoteId) {
      ar.push(e.createFootnote.footnoteId)
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();

  // Retrieve the object after footnotes were created.
  const { footnotes } = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);

  // Inserting texts to footnotes.
  const requests2 = footnoteIds.reduce((ar, id, i) => {
    const o = footnotes[id]
    if (o) {
      ar.push({ insertText: { location: { segmentId: id, index: o.content[0].endIndex - 1 }, text: texts[i].replace(/\(|\)/g, "") } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests: requests2 }, documentId);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided sample Google Document, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used in your provided Google Document. If you change Google Documents, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thanks, that's incredible and basically solved everything instead of just giving me the answer. 

Correction to your code: your location for footnote and range for deletion should read "f.startIndex" instead of "e.startIndex". 
I was trying to see why your code worked on my sample file, but not on real -- and turns out sometimes a paragraph is split into several elements (you accounted for that by introducing f, basically) -- and then we should index things with f as well (as the offset for c will be from f).

I suggest you edit it for some future potential users.

And thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Serge Valkovsky Thank you for replying. About your reply, I understand it. So, I updated the script. Please confirm it. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.